# ios how to replace comma with dot in a NSString, but only for numbers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, replace, nsregularexpression

Let's say i have a string with this format:

"1,3 litres of water, 2,5 pounds of something ,1,4 pounds of something else"

I would like to obtain an array with elements from the string, elements that are separated by ",".

how could i replace the "," with ".", but only when it is between 2 digits?

So the initial array would look like :
"1.3 litres of water, 2.5 pounds of something ,1.4 pounds of something else"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to accomplish that:

```
NSString *string = @"1,3 litres of water, 2,5 pounds of something ,1,4 pounds of something else";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]+),([0-9]+)" options:0 error:nil];
NSString * newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) withTemplate:@"$1.$2"];
NSLog(@"%@", newString); // 1.3 litres of water, 2.5 pounds of something ,1.4 pounds of something else
```

Now if you want to separate that into an array, you can do the following:

```
NSArray *array = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

generically speaking create a regex that does the following: 
replace `(\d+),(\d+)` with `$1\.$2`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html